# How to update live tiles in windows 10 using c++

Tags: c++, uwp, win-universal-app

The `NotificationsExtensions::TileContent` in windows 8.1 doesn't work in windows 10.

Therefore, I am using TileUpdateManager for live tiles, but live tiles doesn't work.
I am using struct like below for `TileUpdateManager` :

```
<tile>
    <visual  version='3'>
        <binding template='TileSquare310x310Image' branding='name'>
            <image id='1' src='ms-appx:///Assets/Tiles/310x310.png' alt='' />
        </binding>
    </visual>
</tile>
```

Is it the right way to use `TileUpdateManager` for live tiles?

What can I use to update live tiles like NotificationsExtensions::TileContent in windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `TileUpdateManager` is the way to do it in Windows 10. Below is a small snippet in `C#`

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(content);  'content is your xml'
TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(document);
updater.Update(notification);
```